# How do I add "drawing" components to a WinForms control?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm using .NET 2.0 Windows Forms and want to add "drawing" components such as lines, rectangles, etc..  I've done this before in MS Access, but I can't seem to find similar things in teh Visual Studio 2005 IDE.  Where do I need to look to find these elements?

Comment: You're looking for the System.Drawing namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using .NET 2 with Windows Forms, one option is to install the [Visual Basic 2005 Power Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=92faa81e-e9c1-432c-8c29-813493a04ecd&displaylang=en) (which is also usable from C#).  It includes a series of [line and shape controls](http://www.getdotnetcode.com/nexDotNet/020030PowerPackLineAndShapeControlsVB2005/PowerPackLineAndShapeControlsVB2005.htm).

Otherwise, you can use GDI+ and the System.Drawing namespace to draw manually.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think I'll be installing the Power Pack at this time.  That's the correct solution, but I'm very surprised that MS didn't include a set of drawing controls in their initial release.

Comment: @Ben: They did, later - but I believe it's part of Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll which ships with .NET 3.0... In 2.0, you need the power pack.  Otherwise, in 2.0, it's using GDI to draw by hand :(

Answer (score 0):

Since these components are not in Visual Studio (the way they were for VB6), you have four choices.

- Draw the lines manually : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyh3c8h8.aspx
- Use labels with borders and modify the height/width to make them LOOK like lines (but this is a hack and won't work for anything other than a straight horizontal or vertical)
- Use 3rd party controls. (I haven't run across any, but I'd bet they exist.)
- Create your own controls using the first option. (this article may prove helpful as well: http://www.vcskicks.com/custom_shape_form_region.php)

Personally, I like options 3 and 4.

**Added**

Hey, here's a good article for option 4!  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289517(VS.71).aspx